# 'Limited' WiFi Connection on Windows 8 Computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, connection, lenovo-laptop

To give some context, the computer I am trying to fix is a Lenovo 10.

It was running on windows 8.1, after the owner updated it to windows 10, they had a bluescreen. They then used a system restore from before the update to bring their computer back to Windows 8.1 in an attempt to resolve the issue.

After doing this, their computer has been unable to connect to the internet, with the connection being described as [limited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg6J4.jpg), this issue includes Ethernet connections and with a network adapter which I tried to use.

Some solutions I have already tried include:

- Updating inbuilt network adapter drivers
- Resetting TCP/IP stack using netsh
- Turning off firewall
- Resetting TCP/IP AutoTuning
- Using Ethernet connection
- Using portable network adapter
- Etc.

Most online solutions I have found to this sort of issue have not done anything for this computer, any fresh ideas on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At this point, why not backup the data and start fresh with a clean install of Win 10. Have you done anything to check for malware? Really, at this point if you want a good running computer, starting over would be much quicker.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running CCleaner,it do remove few of the obsolete registry entries from the settings which may not be needed anymore in windows 10.
Do a full clean up with CCleaner and do install the drivers for the motherboard and network adapter followed by a restart.
Let us know if the above step did anything.

Comment: Suggesting a registry cleaner is going to fix this problem is completely ridiculous, and irresponsible.

Comment: Yea no change, attempting to update to windows 10 again as this seems to be a recurring issue with Windows 8.1